# Gradle failed when I am re debugging code

Tags: flutter, dependencies, importerror

I am not able to re debug or re run my flutter project , I try flutter clean , flutter pub get , but one thing I still not fully installed vsc that's why I am facing this issue ,if yes please then tell me which vsc pack best for full stack app development

Comment: Sorry my tags are posted wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.